# Need help creating triggers phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to add triggers to a table in phpmyadmin by going to the triggers tab in my DB. I add all of the information for the trigger, and get the following error message:

> #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Whenever I try to either add SUPER privileges, OR change the flag log_bin_trust_function_creators by calling `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`, phpmyadmin says:

> #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

So I'm stuck. I need to have SUPER privileges in order to either a) grant myself SUPER privileges or b) change the log_bin_trust_funciton_creators flag

Basically I just need to add triggers to my DB, but this seems to be causing me problems.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the proper permissions. Ask your database or system administrator to give you the SUPER privilege.

> I need to have SUPER privileges in order to either a) grant myself SUPER privileges

Well, technically you need to get another user who already has SUPER privileges to grant them to you; you can't do it to yourself.

According to the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger), MySQL versions beginning with 5.1.6 don't require the SUPER privilege for creating triggers but instead require the TRIGGER privilege, so if your administrator is hesitant to grant you SUPER privileges they may be more willing to upgrade MySQL.

Comment: I'm using AWS, so technically I am the system administrator. So I ended up setting up a new EC2 instance and starting from scratch and was able to get triggers set up. Thanks.